# How to use pre order bonus items?

Tags: xbox-360, assassins-creed-3

I have an [Amazon preorder bonus](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/feature.html?ie=UTF8&docId=1000639653) code for Assassins Creed 3. I followed the steps to get the bonus items -

```
From the main menu of your game, go to the Extras section, 
select 'Exclusive Content', and then input your unique code.
```

Well, I did go through all of the steps okay and entered the code, it was accepted too, but I don't see any difference or where to wear the Aquila's uniform or get the boarding axe.. I thought I might have made a mistake and tried to enter the code again, but it just says the code has already been used up.

Is there something else I need to do in order to get the mentioned items?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access this content, you must have completed Sequence 6 in the story to gain access to the Homestead. This is also around the time you will become the Captain of the Aquila, so the costume will be more appropriate.

Comment: I am in Sequence 5 now.. but will I just have go to any general shop (``£`` shop) and buy them?

Comment: @iamserious - You already will have them once you reach far enough in the game.

Comment: Okay, great - I assume that they will be in the basement of Achilles' house.. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

You need To go to aqueilas house and enter ssabmud